# flutter: how to pass a callback (or other parameters) to widgets in a generated list?

Tags: flutter, dart

What I'm currently doing is generating a list of menu option Widgets, and attempting to have the onPressed of the buttons correspond to a route based on a map, like this:

```
var activityMenuButtonMap = {
'Welcome': ActivityMenuButton(
  text: 'Welcome',
  route: WelcomeScreen(),
  icon: Icon(Icons.filter),
  color: Colors.green[100]
),
'SingleDigitEdit': ActivityMenuButton(
  text: 'Single Digit [View/Edit]',
  route: SingleDigitEditScreen(),
  icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
  color: Colors.amber[100]
),
'SingleDigitPractice': ActivityMenuButton(
  text: 'Single Digit [Practice]',
  route: SingleDigitPracticeScreen(),
  icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
  color: Colors.amber[200]
),
'SingleDigitMultipleChoiceTest': ActivityMenuButton(
  text: 'Single Digit [Multiple Choice Test]',
  route: SingleDigitMultipleChoiceTestScreen(),
  icon: Icon(Icons.filter_1),
  color: Colors.amber[300]
),
};

class ActivityMenuButton {
  String text;
  Widget route;
  Icon icon;
  Color color;

  ActivityMenuButton({this.text, this.route, this.icon, this.color});
}
```

Here's the generated List of my custom MainMenuOption:

```
  List<Widget> getTodo() {
    // iterate over all unlocked activities, and determine which belong in to-do
    List<MainMenuOption> mainMenuOptions = [];
    for (String activity in availableActivities) {  // <---------------
      if (activityStates[activity] != null && activityStates[activity].state == 'todo') {
        mainMenuOptions.add(MainMenuOption(
          text: activityMenuButtonMap[activity].text,
          route: activityMenuButtonMap[activity].route,
          icon: activityMenuButtonMap[activity].icon,
          color: activityMenuButtonMap[activity].color,
          fontSize: itemSize,
        ));
      }
    }
    return mainMenuOptions;
  }
```

But if I try and add my callback function to the route in the `activityMenuButtonMap`, I get the error `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`. [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
final callback;
```

and pass this callback after constructor
initializes a class-level field. This code is executed before the constructor is completed and the object fully initialized, therefore accessing this. (implicit or explicit) is forbidden because it can't be guaranteed that what you attempt to access is already initialized.